# How are you able to extract a count within a StructValue in Django framework?

Tags: python, html, django

My html code in Django is `{{ self }}`  and it will output as follows

```
StructValue([('Title', 'Product 30'), ('Image', None), 
('Cards', [StructValue([('Document', <Document: blah>)])])])
```

How am I able to manipulate this HTML to get the number of documents within `{{ self.cards }}`?

For example i have tried `{{ self.cards.document.count }}` with no success. Am I even just looking at this the wrong way?